# How to get GoogleSheet_ID to use it in 'google_drive' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have user `google_drive` gem, Using oAuth2 I have received the access_token details too. But while I am going to fetch content of one of my google sheet, I found error notfound as like below :

```
notFound: File not found: 1s-APBHuCQLhvAFUeAQyFpyJJiNwyy_ZenQUe91WDru0
```

Below is my code :

```
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(@client) // @client is my googleAuth Object
sheet = session.spreadsheet_by_key("1s-APBHuCQLhvAFUeAQyFpyJJiNwyy_ZenQUe91WDru0").worksheets[0]
```

My Sheet URL is : `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s-APBHuCQLhvAFUeAQyFpyJJiNwyy_ZenQUe91WDru0/edit#gid=0`

Please help me out to find Google Sheet Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ID you are using is correct, maybe other reason is causing this issue.

If you check the [Google Drive API error](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#404_file_not_found_fileid),

> 404: File not found: {fileId}
>
> The user does not have read access to a file, or the file does not
>   exist.
>
> Suggested action: Report to users that they do not have read access to
>   the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should
>   ask the owner for permission to the file.

Maybe you are missing some [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing). Try to use the full permission with this.

Comment: Yes, Exactly.. Thank you